# Regular Expressions javascript how to check aa_bb

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to look for 2 digit string in URL. For example:

```
www.abc.com/ff_gg/abc
```

I can check it with:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("ff_gg") > -1) {
    // 
} else ...
```

but **ff**_**gg** can be a random string. How to use regex to save `ff` and `gg` from a url as a variable ? `ff` and `gg` will be separated by `_`.

Comment: Is `/(\d{2}_\d{2})/` sufficient?

Comment: both ff and gg are digits ?

Comment: these are letters

Comment: so you are looking for 2 times the same letter ? *2 digit string* is confusing

Comment: `/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/(\d{2}_\d{2})(?:\/|$)/.exec(window.location.href)[1]`?

Comment: sorry if I'm confusing.. I want to search for ff or gg in my link and save it as a variable. gg_ff can be: 2 random letters _ 2 random letters. like: di_fu or ye_nv

Comment: [String#search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) `/[a-z]{2}_[a-z]{2}/i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`String#search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) with a regex, instead of [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexof). Or [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Also see [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to understand the expression.

```js
const text = 'www.abc.com/ff_gg/abc';
const rx = /\/[a-z]{2}_[a-z]{2}\//i;
if (text.search(rx) > -1) {
  console.log('found');
} else {
  console.log('not found');
}
if (rx.test(text)) {
  console.log('found');
} else {
  console.log('not found');
}
```

You could use a similar regex to [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and capture, or [`RegExp#exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

Alternatively use string manipulation with [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) or [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

As you see, there are several options (and even more that I've not mentioned) but I don't have time just now to create an example for each.

```js
const text = 'www.abc.com/ff_gg/abc';
const match = text.match(/\/([a-z]{2})_([a-z]{2})\//i);
if (match) {
  console.log(match);
}
```

```js
const text = 'www.abc.com/ff_gg/abc';
const rx = /\/[a-z]{2}_[a-z]{2}\//i;
const index = text.search(rx);
if (index > -1) {
  console.log(text.slice(index + 1, index + 1 + 5).split('_'));
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why you need to check greater then -1, when you're using search?

Comment: [`String#search: Returns the index of the first match between the regular expression and the given string; if not found, -1.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search#Return_value)

Answer (score 1):

```
([a-zA-Z]{2})_([a-zA-Z]{2})
```

2 capturing groups separated by _ can do the trick for the regex.

Then use `match()` who will return the matched groups

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/pB4cF2/2)

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you can make a `RegExp` object. For more information about the `RegExp` object see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

The following example should work:

```js
var url = "www.abc.com/ff_gg/abc";
var reg = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z]{2})_([a-zA-Z]{2})");

if (reg.test(url)) {
  var matches = url.match(reg);
  var ff = matches[1];
  var gg = matches[2];
  
  console.log("group1: " + ff);
  console.log("group2: " + gg);
  console.log("do something");
}
```

Here is also a example of the regex: http://regexr.com/3e8a7

Comment: `\w: Matches any alphanumeric character from the basic Latin alphabet, including the underscore. Equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_].`

Comment: Thanks, i change it to [a-zA-Z].